# Why the difference of labeled/unlabeled argument results different return?

Tags: ocaml, reason

I just started learning Reason(OCaml) and I don't understand the titled thing. Why the second part returns function but not calculated value? I thought that only a way of passing argument differs and a result doesn't.

```
let addWithoutLabel = (~x=10) => (y) => x + y;
let fifteen = addWithoutLabel(5);
Js.log(fifteen)
/* 15 */

let addWithLabel = (~x=10) => (~y) => x + y;
let sixteen = addWithLabel(~y=6);
Js.log(sixteen)
/* 
function sixteen(param) {
  return addWithLabel(param, 6);
}
*/
```

https://reasonml.github.io/en/try.html?rrjsx=true&reason=DYUwLgBAhgJjDqBLMALA9gVzAGSgIxGAgF4IAKAPwA9iBGABgEoSA+cgT2eLaogGoI7ANwAoUJABmiCWBAgAdiWhwkqTDnyEyAVkaiAUgGcAdMDQBzMlJlz5jEQHoAVBFraIThyLHhlCZCi4BESklDQMXGyUnKwQvALCPpCGiFSyCkqw-qhBWhTsxABseiJGphZkKWm29s4QIhIY8gDGYIhoilXp8mQADlAATlAAtswA3iIQEAPgGAOKWaqBmsB9gyMANBDFogC+Ip5AA

Comment: I don't know Reason syntax and I don't want to post examples in OCaml syntax. The prerequisite for you here is to understand partial application. Then the answer to the question is: it's because labeled arguments can be passed in any order. The solution is to always define functions with at least one non-labeled argument, possibly `()` if all other arguments are labeled. Don't write `let f ?x y = ...` but write `let f ?x ~y () = ...` or `let f ?x y = ...`.

Comment: @MartinJambon You can easily convert between the two syntaxes with Reason Try: https://reasonml.github.io/en/try

Comment: @MartinJambon your 'don't write' code and the second 'write' code look the same to me...

Comment: @Yawar thanks for the catch. It's `let f ?x ~y = ...` that should not be used.

Comment: @MartinJambon So it means function is invoked when all of the non-labeled argument has satisfied?

Answer (score 3):

It is required to have at least one positional parameter when there are optional labeled arguments (or as in your case, arguments with a default parameter). Otherwise Reason expects from you that you want to use the partially applied function.

To ensure the full application, use a unit `()` in both the function declaration and function invocation to tell the compiler that you want to omit the `~x` parameter.

```
let addWithoutLabel = (~x=10) => (y) => x + y;
let fifteen = addWithoutLabel(5);
Js.log(fifteen)
/* 15 */

let addWithLabel = (~x=10) => (~y, ()) => x + y;
let sixteen = addWithLabel(~y=6, ());
Js.log(sixteen)
/* 16 */
```

https://reasonml.github.io/en/try.html?rrjsx=true&reason=DYUwLgBAhgJjDqBLMALA9gVzAGSgIxGAgF4IAKAPwA9iBGABgBoIBPAShID4IqIBqVgG4AUKEgAzROLAgQAOxLQ4SVJhz5CZAKxsRAKQDOAOmBoA5mUnTZc3cID0AKgi0tER-eGjwShMhS4BESklDQMHMTclCzMZGwR3LwCLCJiEAaIVDLyirB+qIGaFCzEAGyx8frGphYZWTZ2Ti6l7p5AA